# First slide of references in beamer starts one line further down

Tags: beamer, spacing, biblatex

When I add slides with references at the end of a `beamer` presentation, the first slide always starts one line further down than the subsequent slides. Why, and how I can prevent it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \nocite{*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t, allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Technically, `\printbibliography` starts a list and thus gets `\topsep` before, you can try the ad hoc `\vspace{-\topsep}\printbibliography`. But maybe there is something more elegant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally `\printbibliography` is a `\list`. The easiest solution I could find to get rid of the space before is simply adding `\vspace{-\topsep}`.

```
\vspace{-\topsep}\printbibliography
```

Comment: If I change the font size in the bibliography with `\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}`, then there's a small difference again between the first slide and subsequent slides. Any idea why that happens? (Let me know if I should open a new question about that)

Comment: @Sverre I think you are better off asking a new question. All the normal tricks don't seem to work. The following MWE reproduces your problem `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t, allowframebreaks]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \item D
    \item E
    \item F
    \item G
    \item H
    \item I
    \item J
    \item K
    \item L
    \item M
    \item N
    \item O
    \item P
    \item Q
    \item R
    \item S
    \item T
    \item U
    \item V
    \item W
    \item X
    \item Y
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: and does not use `biblatex` at all. It seems that beamer does add some additional space besides `\topsep` and `\partopsep`