# Align beamer slides with frame breaks

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, vertical-alignment, lists, itemize

As addressed in [First slide of references in beamer starts one line further down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275872/first-slide-of-references-in-beamer-starts-one-line-further-down), a bibliography across several slides is not vertically aligned from the first slide to the next. In that case, it seems to be sufficient to remove an apparent `topsep` introduced by the bibliography (see [moewe's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275966/9077)).

But when I reduce the font size of the bibliography, the top of the list on the first slide is once again not aligned with the following slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\nocite{*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t, allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}
    \vspace{-\topsep}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In this MWE, the misalignment is quite small, but in my actual document, the misalignment is much bigger. What causes this behavior, and how can I undo it?

[moewe suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275872/first-slide-of-references-in-beamer-starts-one-line-further-down/275966?noredirect=1#comment668059_275966) that this is the same problem as what occurs when an item list is broken across several slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t, allowframebreaks]
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \item D
    \item E
    \item F
    \item G
    \item H
    \item I
    \item J
    \item K
    \item L
    \item M
    \item N
    \item O
    \item P
    \item Q
    \item R
    \item S
    \item T
    \item U
    \item V
    \item W
    \item X
    \item Y
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253185/inconsistent-slide-margins-in-frame-with-allowframebreaks-option-in-beamer

Comment: The issue is also addresses from the beamer maintainer (at least I think that it is related): https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/325